# PHP fread not returning string

Tags: php, logging, fread

```
    log_email("email to: " . $to . " at: " . $time);
}

function log_email($message){
    $dir = dirname(__FILE__);
    $filename = $dir . "/logs/email_log.txt";       
        echo $filename;

    if(is_readable($filename)){        
        $handle = fopen($filename, "w+");
        $contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
        fwrite($handle, $message . "\n" . $contents);
        fclose($handle); 
    }else{
        echo 'The file is not readable.';
    }
}
```

The file has 777 access, the file contains some text.
I get a warning up saying: *Warning: fread(): Length parameter must be greater than 0 in* ...

$contents variable ends up containing nothing? Any ideas?
The directory must be correct because if i delete the file, my is_readable returns false.

Comment: What does `var_dump(filesize($filename));` show?

Comment: the contents of the file is: "email to: ************************* at: 28/11/2012 03:05:48 pm"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are [truncating](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) the file when you initially open it with this line.

```
$handle = fopen($filename, "w+");
```

So the size will be zero at that point triggering that warning.

You should probably do something like this:

```
function log_email($message){
    $dir = dirname(__FILE__);
    $filename = $dir . "/logs/email_log.txt";       
        echo $filename;

    if(is_readable($filename)){        
        // This will append to the file without destroying its contents
        $handle = fopen($filename, "a+"); 
        fwrite($handle, $message . "\n");
        fclose($handle); 
    }else{
        echo 'The file is not readable.';
    }
}
```